# WPF ContextMenu using (Shift-Right-Click)

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, shift, right-click

I have a question with the "ContextMenu" in WPF. Is there a way to have the context menu pop up only if a "Shift-Right-Click" was performed??
I have been looking all over the place for this. The ContextMenu seems to only be able to pop up when a "right-click" is made.

Anyone have any idea's ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.... your XAML context menu properties should look like this...

```
<ElementToWhichContextMenuIsAttached ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}"
                                     ContextMenuOpening="MyContextMenuOpening"/>
```

And your code behind will look like this.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This will suppress the context menu if the shift key is not pressed
    /// </summary>
    private void MyContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        // Show context menu as handled if no key is down.
        e.Handled = !(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift));
    }
```

Comment: Sweet it works tnx! BTW you don't have to use a StaticResource, you can just set it as the content but "ContextMenuOpening" will be the same as you have it. I'm using it in a infragistics control, so I have to do it that way.